# How to export a file as a .lar file programmatically?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to export a file as a .lar file. I tried with the following code which basically converts a file as . zip file in which I replaced the .zip extension with the .lar extension .The code is as follows:-

```
ClassLoader cl = PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader();
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class, cl)
            .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("structureId").eq(structureId1+""));
List<JournalArticle> list=JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
Iterator<JournalArticle> itr=list.iterator();
JournalArticle journalArticle=null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    journalArticle=itr.next();
    System.out.println(journalArticle);
    sb.append(journalArticle);
}
File f = new File("d:\\test.lar");
ZipOutputStream out1 = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry("d:\\mytext.txt");
out1.putNextEntry(e);
byte[] data1 = sb.toString().getBytes();
out1.write(data1, 0, data1.length);
out1.closeEntry();

out1.close();
```

Actually I am able to make a .lar file using the above code. But when I tried to import this file, I got the message- The file test.lar cannot be imported. I got no messages in the log. I think I missed some necessary configuration files. Please specify what should I do to import the file. Thanx in advance..

Comment: Did you refer to Liferay src code for method used by liferay for creating a lar.Please refer the same for creating a lar.

Comment: @Shivam: Thanx for the response..but can u tell me the name of that method..please.

Comment: I do not have the portal-src right now,but if not there,you can download liferay-portal-src,check the portlet which is used by liferay in control panel for the same purpose and search for the code(method) used to achieve the same.

Comment: I searched a lot but could not get..if you know then please tell